# Image Preview with jQuery, change the Hover image size

Tags: javascript, html, css

This should be a very simple question:

I am trying to use [Easiest Tooltip and Image Preview Using jQuery](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery)
I am trying to use this [example](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/)

it is working fine for me,

my question is how can I change the hover image size (the one that is displayed in the tooltip once I am hovering the small one)
my image is too big and I want to set it size to 200px x 200px
how can I do that?

this is the current style:

```
<style>
#preview{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#333;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    }
</style>
```

this is the Javascript:

```
this.imagePreview = function(){ 
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.preview").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});
```

this is the main:

```
<a href="1.jpg" /*class="preview"*/><img src="1s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
#preview img {
  height:200px;
}
```

or change

```
    $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");
```

to

```
    $("body").append('<p id="preview"><img style="height:200px" src="'+ this.href +'" alt="Image preview" />'+ c +'</p>');
```

or

```
    $("body").append('<p id="preview"><img style="width:200px" src="'+ this.href +'" alt="Image preview" />'+ c +'</p>');
```

depending on how you want to restrict it

Comment: add "width: auto;" also to maintain aspect ratio of the image

Comment: @Playmaker - I do not think that is necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vcEda/

Comment: Oh thanks! There was a query on stackoverflow related to the same (how to have images with aspect ratio maintained?). There the answer came out to have auto.